# How to use a common interface between SerialPort and NetworkStream in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have a C# method _TryReadChunk that reads bytes from a SerialPort connection:

```
private bool _TryReadChunk(SerialPort connection, int n_exp, out byte[] received)
{
    ...
    received = new byte[n_exp];
    int bytes_read = connection.Read(received, length, n_exp);
    ...
}
```

I need the same method again, but reading from a NetworkStream. I thought that an elegant way to do this would be to use a generic method like

```
private bool _TryReadChunk<T> (T connection, int n_exp, out byte[] received)
{
    ...
}
```

However, I somehow need to add a constraint to the method that T has to implement a Read method. First I thought to define an interface like

```
interface _CanRead 
{
    int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);
}
```

and require

```
private bool _TryReadChunk<T> (T connection, int n_exp, out byte[] received) where T : _CanRead
{
    ...
}
```

but when reading more I got the impression that SerialPort and NetworkStream would have to implement that interface explicitly, which, of course, they don't.

I am new to generics and feel a bit stuck. Is there a way to do what I want or should I just bite the bullet and implement my method twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't a good application for generics, but it is for using base classes. SerialPort has a property called BaseStream, which is a Stream. NetworkStream also derives from stream, so you could do something like this:

```
private bool _TryReadChunk(Stream connection, int n_exp, out byte[] received)
{
    ...
}
```

Then pass in the [SerialPort.BaseStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.basestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object or the NetworkStream object, you can then use the standard Stream.Read methods to read the data out the same way.

Comment: Thanks. I had checked for a common base class, but not for a common base class between properties.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to re implement which is already available. You can use the `SerialPort.BaseStream` property and use it directly.

`NetworkStream` is already a `Stream` and `SerialPort.BaseStream` exposes a `Stream`. You can take `Stream` as a parameter to your `TryReadChunk` method and read the stream directly.